# Python seaborn catplot - How do I change the y-axis scale to percentage

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In the figure the y-axis labels are in decimals from (0 to 1) i.e (0.1, 0.2, 0.4 etc).  How can I convert this into a % format (10%, 20%, 40% etc).  Just 10, 20, 40 also will do.

Thanks, John

```
g = sns.catplot(x="who", y="survived", col="class",
...                 data=titanic, saturation=.5,
...                 kind="bar", ci=None, aspect=.6)
```

Answer (score 10):

You may use a `PercentFormatter` on the axes of the grid.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.catplot(x="who", y="survived", col="class",
                 data=titanic, saturation=.5,
                 kind="bar", ci=None, aspect=.6)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.show()
```

[image]